# undefined reference on linux but works fine on mac

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, ld

I am trying to execute the following:

```
gcc -Ilibconfig controller.c -o Controller libconfig/libconfig.a
```

but what I get is:

```
In function `processConfigFile':
controller.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `config_init'
controller.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `config_read_file'
controller.c:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `config_destroy'
controller.c:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `config_lookup_string'
controller.c:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `config_lookup_string'
controller.c:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `config_lookup_string'
controller.c:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `config_lookup_string'
controller.c:(.text+0x317): undefined reference to `config_lookup_string'
controller.c:(.text+0x36e): undefined reference to `config_lookup'
controller.c:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `config_setting_length'
controller.c:(.text+0x454): undefined reference to `config_setting_get_string_elem'
controller.c:(.text+0x4fa): undefined reference to `config_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now I can understand that the linker is failing to link the library,however I have made sure that the library comes after the files and this works just fine on OSX, I have no idea why this is happening.

Please if anybody could help out.

Thanks

Comment: Does switching the order of command line arguments help? i.e. calling `gcc -Ilibconfig -o Controller libconfig/libconfig.a controller.c`

Comment: Was `libconfig/libconfig.a` rebuilt from scratch on the Linux system? Trying to link an OSX library to a Linux executable may get a bit wonky...

Answer (score 2):

You should be linking the libraryas a library, not as object code.

```
gcc -Ilibconfig controller.c -o Controller -Llibconfig -lconfig
```

Linux and OS X use completely different linkers, so they may behave differently in the kind of files they accept.

Comment: I am skeptical. Listing a file on the command line does not mean it is an object file; the gcc command and the linker are capable of recognizing different types of files and processing them appropriately. `-lconfig” is just an abbreviation for “libconfig with any library suffix”, and “-L” just adds a directory to check for library files. The problem is more likely either a path problem (libconfig/libconfig.a is not present in “.” in the Linux system) or a problem in the library (not built correctly, not indexed, et cetera).

Comment: It looks like I need to build the library again and the .a file that I generated on OSX would not work on linux. Does this mean, I need the entire libconfig source in my project and have to build it everytime I build my project? like do ./configure and then make every single time?

Comment: If that's really the reason then you only have to build it when checking out a fresh copy of your project sources. Not every time you build the project.

Comment: So does this mean that I have a ./configure script for my project that builds it? and then generates a makefile..?

Comment: Now I have installed http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libconfig-dev , but still the same problem persists..